# Django DB design Guidance

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have an app that will track insects collected in traps. Field agents will be taking readings periodically so that we may have an accurate count of all `pests` in all `traps`. We will then display the data for each specific trap location with bugs in columns and dates in rows.

Seems straightforward enough.

`models.py` (simplified)

```
class Trap(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Pest(models.Model):
    common_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Reading(models.Model):
    trap = models.ForeignKey(Trap, related_name='readings')
    read_time = models.DateTimeField()
    pest = models.ManyToManyField(Pest, through='PestCount')

class PestCount(models.Model):
    pest = models.ForeignKey(Pest)
    reading = models.ForeignKey(Reading)
    count = models.IntegerField()
```

The thing is, I would like to define `pests` for each `trap` rather than for each `reading`. That way, admins could define what pests are being tracked, and field agents could just put in numbers.

But I'm not sure what a pest count would look like if I change the relationship. Because a reading couldn't be for *any* pest, it can only be for pest(s) associated with its trap.

Does this make sense?

EDIT: I've decided this was a silly idea. The schema is correct as is. I'll add some front-end stuff to pre-populate pests on the form.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little unclear, are you asking how you would get the total count for pests in a specific trap? I.e.

```
trap = Trap.objects.get(name="Fly Trap")
pest = Pest.objects.get(common_name="House Fly")

total_pest_count = PestCount.objects.filter(
    reading__trap=trap,
    pest=pest
).aggregate(Sum('count'))
```

Untested, should work though. Aggregation docs page [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/).

Or are you wanting to change your database schema for another reason?

Comment: I was considering changing the schema to allow me to limit certain `pests` to certain `traps`. But, after spending some time on the whiteboard, I've decided to keep it as is. Thanks for your help! I'll vote you up.